# Ubuntu /boot partition stay in mode "Filesystem state: not clean" (tune2fs)

Tags: ubuntu, tune2fs

I have the problem with my /boot partition on a ubuntu "Ubuntu 11.10" system. Maybe also on "Ubuntu 12.04 lts" but I cannot verify this, because it's a prodctive system.

If I umount the /boot partition, make a fsck.ext2 everything seem ok, see the log.

But if I remount the /boot everything is pretty much the same as before, tune2fs shows 'state : not clean'

What do I wrong and more important can I do something without rebooting the system?

Best Regards,
Axel

The situation:

```
Mount-Point
# mount -v | grep "^/" | awk '{print "\nPartition identifier: " $1  "\n Mountpoint: "  $3}'
Partition identifier: /dev/mapper/nvidia_fjdedcdd1
Mountpoint: /boot

# tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/nvidia_fjdedcdd1 | grep -iE '(state|error)'
Filesystem state:         not clean
Errors behavior:          Continue

# umount /boot

# fsck.ext2 -f /dev/mapper/nvidia_fjdedcdd1
e2fsck 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
Durchgang 1: Prüfe Inodes, Blocks, und Größen
Durchgang 2: Prüfe Verzeichnis Struktur
Durchgang 3: Prüfe Verzeichnis Verknüpfungen
Durchgang 4: Überprüfe die Referenzzähler
Durchgang 5: Überprüfe Gruppe Zusammenfassung
boot: 250/124496 Dateien (11.6% nicht zusammenhängend), 104110/248832 Blöcke

# tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/nvidia_fjdedcdd1 | grep -iE '(state|error)'
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue

# mount -v -t ext2 -o defaults /dev/mapper/nvidia_fjdedcdd1 /boot

# tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/nvidia_fjdedcdd1 | grep -iE '(state|error)'
Filesystem state:         not clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
```

Answer (score 3):

This is normal. The filesystem is always "not clean" while it is mounted. There is no problem to be fixed.

Comment: Is this valid for the /boot partition only?

Other partitions are in clean state while they are mounted. Do you know a document or manual entry which descripts this behavior.